# JCuda: doing parallel arithmetic operations on arrays?

Tags: java, cuda, parallel-processing

I just can't find examples for `JCuda` for one of simplest tasks: add two arrays of values to a third array.

I always only find C/C++ examples, which rely on some CUDA-precompiler, hence unusable for me. Scary things occur there, such as:

```
VecAdd<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, N)
```

Well, in JCuda libraries there is nothing similar to `VecAdd`.

There are a lot of sub-libraries in JCuda, such as `JCudpp`, `JCublas`, ... I really don't know **where** to look and for **what**.

**Please help!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to assemble a working example:

### Source

```
import java.util.*;

import jcuda.*;
import static jcuda.jcublas.JCublas.*;

public class Main {

  private static final int VECTOR_SIZE = 10;

  static {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        cublasShutdown();
      }

    }));

    cublasInit();
  }

  static void printArrays(float[] a1, float[] a2) {
    System.out.println("\t" + Arrays.toString(a1));
    System.out.println("\t" + Arrays.toString(a2));
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float[] a1 = new float[VECTOR_SIZE];
    float[] a2 = new float[VECTOR_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < VECTOR_SIZE; ++i) {
      a1[i] = i + 1;
    }

    Pointer p1 = new Pointer();
    Pointer p2 = new Pointer();

    cublasAlloc(VECTOR_SIZE, Sizeof.FLOAT, p1);
    cublasAlloc(VECTOR_SIZE, Sizeof.FLOAT, p2);

    System.out.println("BEFORE:");
    printArrays(a1, a2);

    cublasSetVector(VECTOR_SIZE, Sizeof.FLOAT, Pointer.to(a1), 1, p1, 1);
    cublasSetVector(VECTOR_SIZE, Sizeof.FLOAT, Pointer.to(a2), 1, p2, 1);

    // THE ACTUAL OPERATION: MULTIPLY AND ADD
    cublasSaxpy(VECTOR_SIZE, 20f, p1, 1, p2, 1);

    cublasGetVector(VECTOR_SIZE, Sizeof.FLOAT, p2, 1, Pointer.to(a2), 1);

    System.out.println("AFTER:");
    printArrays(a1, a2);

    cublasFree(p1);
    cublasFree(p2);
  }

}
```

### Output

```
BEFORE:
    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

AFTER:
    [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
    [20.0, 40.0, 60.0, 80.0, 100.0, 120.0, 140.0, 160.0, 180.0, 200.0]
```

### Note

Now I will play around with [`AMD Aparapi`](http://developer.amd.com/zones/java/aparapi/Pages/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would play with **JCublas**. Thanks to that you would be able to use CUBLAS, the NVIDIA CUDA implementation of the [Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms), in Java applications.

The example provided on following page: http://www.jcuda.de/jcuda/jcudpp/JCudpp.html is pretty complete.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to find a solution that I understand, assembled from different examples. I will post in separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VecAdd function written in C/C++. It seems that JCuda can only load cubin files, which makes sense,as the cuda code is not even created by the C compiler. So you can use the built-in functions in JCublas or create a function in C and create a cubin file. This function can be launched in JCuda.